# Writing Secret Key and IV spec to an external file and reading them?

Tags: java, xml, encryption, secret-key, cbc-mode

I have a method that encrypts values using Cipher CBC mode before inserting them into my MySQL table as follows:

```
public void addFruit(String fruit, String color, int pos){
            CryptoHelperClass crypto = new CryptoHelperClass();

            //Crypto Cipher 
            SecretKeyIVGen sk = new SecretKeyIVGen();  
            List<KeyGenerator> kgList = sk.getKeyGenerator();
            List<SecretKey> skList = sk.getSecretKey(kgList);  //how do I save the skList value generated here and write it into an external (XML) file?
            List<IvParameterSpec> ivList = sk.getIvSpec(skList);  //how do I save the ivList value generated here and write it into an external (XML) file? 

            byte[] byteFruit = crypto.encrypt(fruit, skList, ivList);
            String bcryptColor = BCryptHelperClass.bCrypt(color);
            byte[] byteColor = crypto.encrypt(bcryptColor, skList, ivList);         

            fdao.insertFruit(byteFruit, byteColor, pos);
        }
```

Within this method, I want to save the `skList` and `ivList` variables and write them to an external file like XML.  These values can only be generated within this method.

My idea is that I will read from this XML file later and use the values when decrypting the data stored in my tables.

How do I write them to an external file and then be able to read and iterate through that file later?

The XML file should have elements like:

```
<entry 1>
     <secretkey> javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8ea9</secretkey>
     <ivspec>javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec@ab4d9e2 </ivspec>
</entry 1>

<entry 2>
     <secretkey>javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@1794a</secretkey>
     <ivspec>javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec@ab4d9e2 </ivspec>
</entry 2>
```

Comment: Why are you using a fixed IV?  Also, you're only storing the references, not the actual values...

Comment: The IV is randomly generated from another class `SecretKeyIVGen` every time this function runs.  And I've read here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138148/saving-key-and-iv-to-file-aes-implementation-crypto  that the IV can be public info.

Comment: The IV ought to be kept together with the encrypted data - as it's only relevant for that perticular encryption. You can put it in front of the encrypted data, so it's readily available when you need to decrypt. As for the key, you could put it in a keystore envented for that purpose .. you would properbly need to split your key generation logic from your encryption logic, so you don't generate a new key each time you encrypt.

Comment: And where is the problem? Simply create / write an XML file with the values. btw - you can use DOMDocument to store/read the whole XML at once (if it fits into memory), just search for it